# Activate a new watch without pairing it to iPhone on WatchOS6

Tags: ios, watchos, watchos-6

Is it possible to activate a new watch without the dependency in an iPhone on WatchOS6?

Apple launched a new watch app store. But they still say that

> watchOS 6 requires iPhone 6s or later with iOS 13 or later
>   [enter link description here](https://www.apple.com/watchos/watchos-preview/)

So it looks like watch will still be dependent of an iPhone. Why than let it install its own apps?

Comment: Watch is dependent on iPhone , Not the applications. make sense

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to install watch apps via iTunes once os6 is available to the public.

Comment: Yes but I can not even initialize it